# Laravel Passport: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-passport

Iam trying to register using passport api authentication. but I got an error

> "message": "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object",
>   "exception": "ErrorException",

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('name', 'email', 'password');

        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required',
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($credentials, $rules);
        if($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['success'=> false, 'error'=> $validator->errors()]);
        }

        $name = $request->name;
        $email = $request->email;
        $password = $request->password;

        $user = User::create(['name' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'password' => bcrypt($password)]);

        $data['token'] = $user->createToken("MyApp")->accessToken();
        $data['name'] = $user->name;
        return response()->json(['success'=> true, 'message'=> $data]);
    }
```

how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

you can run again:

> `php artisan passport:install`